# AdamOptimizer defies tf.control_dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow

Somehow, `AdamOptimizer` defies `tf.control_dependencies`.

Here is a test. I ask TensorFlow to do the following:

1. calculate loss
2. calculate loss
3. run one step of adam

I use [tf.control_dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to "ensure" TF would run Step 3 after running step 2.

If TensorFlow does these 3 steps in the right order, the result of step 1 and 2 should be the same.

But that is not the case. What is wrong?

---

Test:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=np.array([1], dtype=np.float64))
loss = x * x

optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1)

## Control Dependencies ##
with tf.control_dependencies([loss]):
    train_op = optim.minimize(loss)

## Run ##
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(1000):
        a = sess.run([loss])
        b = sess.run([loss, train_op])[0]
        print(a, b)
        assert np.allclose(a, b)
```

Result:

```
[array([1.])] [2.50003137e-14]
AssertionError
```

The result of step 1 and 2 are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making step 3 depending on `tf.identity(loss)` would magically fix the problem.

What is going on??

Magical fix:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=np.array([1], dtype=np.float64))
loss = x * x

optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1)

## Control Dependencies ##
loss2 = tf.identity(loss)  # <--- this #
with tf.control_dependencies([loss2]):
    train_op = optim.minimize(loss)

## Run ##
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(1000):
        a = sess.run([loss])
        b = sess.run([loss2, train_op])[0]  # <--- loss2
        print(a, b)
        assert np.allclose(a, b)
```

Result:

```
[array([1.])] [1.]
[array([2.50003137e-14])] [2.50003137e-14]
[array([0.4489748])] [0.4489748]
...
[array([1.151504e-47])] [1.151504e-47]
[array([4.90468459e-46])] [4.90468459e-46]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting `sess.run([loss, adam_op])` to run `loss`, then run `adam_op`. Alas, sess.run doesn't work that way. Take this simpler example -- it prints `1.0 1.0`, indicating that the `set_x` op is run before `get_x`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

var_x = tf.get_variable("x", shape=[], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
get_x = var_x.read_value()
set_x = var_x.assign(1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    a, b = sess.run([get_x, set_x])
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: I thought `tf.control_dependencies` would ensure tensorflow runs loss before adam. Your example does not use  `tf.control_dependencies`. doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies

Comment: It *does* run loss before Adam -- it would do so even if you didn't use control_dependencies at all. However, loss depends on the variable that Adam updates, so it must be calculated again afterwards.